# How can I get a list of all classes I import from a module in Python 3?

Tags: python

I want to create a list consisting of the names of all classes I import from a certain folder.

At the moment I have something like this:

```py
from .my_classes import Class1, Class2, Class3
list_of_classes = [Class1.__name__, Class2.__name__, Class3.__name__]
```

But I want to convert it to something less manual:

```py
from .my_classes import *

# .my_classes is obviously not working
list_of_classes = [cls.__name__ for cls in .my_classes]
```

How can I get `.my_classes` as a list?

`.my_classes` is a folder with this structure:

```
my_classes
|
|--__init__.py
|--some_classes_here.py
|--some_more_classes_here.py
```

Comment: Perhaps you could start with the names of the classes and programmatically import them.

Comment: Maybe you can just `import my_classes`?

Comment: What do you need the list of names for?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the imported objects become attributes of your module.
So calling `vars()` will put all the parameters.

If you put it after your import you should see it.

Please note that if you import `import x as y` you will see `y` and not `x`

example:

```
import collections
import re
print([x for x in vars() if  not (x.startswith('__') and x.endswith('__'))])
['collections', 're']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()` to collect the names in your current namespace and then inspect which module they came from using the `__module__` attribute.  This only works for classes and functions.

```
from .my_classes import *

classes = []
for name, item in locals().copy().items():
    try:
        if item.__module__ == 'my_classes':
            classes.append(item.__name__)
    except AttributeError:
        continue

classes
# returns:
['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3']
```